# Difference between constructors

Tags: php

Not really sure how to search this, but is there really a difference between these two?

```
$t = new Test();
// vs...
$t = new Test;
```

Comment: no, these are the same

Comment: Using `$t = new Test;` will save you 2 keystrokes ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, for pointing out the dupes. They didn't show up when i was searching!

Comment: I always request the use of () an instantiation is a method call and so should mirror other function / method calls in your code.  no real difference operationally though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. The **__construct()** method is executed with both.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally accepted rules and they must adhere to.

```
$t = new Test();
```

True choise

Comment: This convention is most likely inherited from Java, which PHP attempts to emulate in some ways, however "true choise" does not make much sense. Could you please clarify ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no differance

Look here:

```
<?php

class Test {
    function printTest() {
        echo "Test";    
    }
}

$t = new Test();
echo $t->printTest();
// vs...

$t = new Test;
echo $t->printTest();

?>
```

Output:

```
Test //from Test()
Test //from Test
```

Answer (score 1):

If the **__construct** method needs to take in some parameters then you should use

```
$t = new Class('Param1','Param2');
```

If it doesn't need to take any parameters then there is no difference between using

```
$t = new Class;
```

OR

```
$t = new Class();
```